# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Cannot find the expected secondary table

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm having some problems with configuring testing environment for Hibernate, Spring, Oracle database (created locally). All beans are normally initialized at startup except "sessionFactory". This exception bugs me:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Cannot find the expected secondary table: no MY_INFORMATION available for net.me.business.model.MyInformation
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.getJoin(Ejb3Column.java:358) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.getTable(Ejb3Column.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.toString(Ejb3Column.java:621) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.bind(Ejb3Column.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.buildColumnFromAnnotation(Ejb3Column.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.buildColumnFromAnnotation(Ejb3Column.java:389) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ColumnsBuilder.extractMetadata(ColumnsBuilder.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1495) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:796) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:707) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:4035) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3989) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1398) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar:3.6.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717) ~[spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188) ~[spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

This is hibernate/spring configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan="net.me.business.model" p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties" />

<util:properties id="hibernateProperties">
  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   <!--<prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=create schema if not exists myschema\;SET SCHEMA myschema\;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</prop>--> 
  <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>-->
</util:properties>
```

I don't have any idea where did I missed something.

Here is github repo. Please take a look:

https://github.com/slavisah/mybusiness.git

There are some notes in README.md

### Question #2

Is there any way to dynamically add same sequence mapping as a ID generator to every table? Without writing annotations in every class. The sequence name template would be [tablename]_SEQ.

Comment: You need to show us your models code for both primary and secondary table. Obviously you have a join of sorts happening and it may be incorrect.

Comment: When I use JPA and persistence.xml everything works fine with same model classes. I just try to change implementation to Hibernate.

Comment: You still need to post the code in as you might have issues with the code, at this stage this question is not of high enough quality for people to give you accurate answers

Comment: You're right. I'm just building git repo to share with you guys to check it out

Comment: Up there I edited my post with git repo https://github.com/slavisah/mybusiness.git So if you have some time, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out where I'm doing wrong. These two don't go together:

```
@Table(name="ADDRESS")
public  class Address implements Serializable {


    @Column(name="MODIFIED_BY",table="ADDRESS",length=100)
    @Basic
    private String modifiedBy;


}
```

`@Table(name="ADDRESS")` at the beginning of the class and `@Column(...table="ADDRESS"...)` on every single field. This mapping was generated by JPA Modeler netbeans plugin. I will not rely on it any more :)

**Question #2** from above is still open for discussion.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Currently JPA Modeler is in development . So please raise your bug [here](https://java.net/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=jpamodeler) with the attachment of JPA Modeler xml .
Thanks for your contribution !